# Printing elements by class in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, class, element

I am working on a project and I am having problems finding elements and printing them out in a Selenium Test. Lets say for this example I am trying to find the headline text from cnn. I am using the following code but I still get an error. I have been trying to use the first line of code but I have read people using the findElements to list all of the specified elements. (which I want because I want all cnn headlines with that class) any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 var myElements = document.getElementById("cd__headline-text")
```

or

```
 driver.findElements(By.className("cd__headline-text")
```

[image: https://www.cnn.com/]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: else throw err ReferenceError: document is not defined at Object. <anonymous>

Comment: When you say cnn's headlines you mean the list of Live updates?

Comment: yes. I was just giving it as an example. this span class is what im after considering there can be multiples on a webpage of ours.                                                      <span class="lm_title">Quick Chart</span>

Comment: If you are writing a Selenium test using JS, you probably shouldn't be referencing `document`. That's likely why you are getting that error. You should be using `driver.findElements()`, etc. What happens when you run your second line of code?

Comment: driver.findElements(By.className("lm_title"); #I am getting else throw error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'findElements' of undefined